# Angular no such file or directory, open '../node_modules/document-register-element/build/document-register-element.js'

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm getting the above error when trying to run an angular 7 application. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

adding `"document-register-element": "^1.7.2"` in the dependencies and npm install solved the problem.